# what is the way to deploy rails apps in digital ocean through windows laptop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

since digital ocean is linux-based and i'm using a windows laptop, the only way to deploy rails apps is using VM to boot Ubuntu OS and deploy from there?

Comment: Do you face any issue when deploying from Windows?

Comment: the tutorial i discovered so far is assuming you are using ubuntu OS (as 'sudo' command not recognized in windows). compared to heroku, its toolbelt apps make deployment easier to heroku. ( been praticing from michael hartl tutorials)

Comment: that doesn't matter.  all of your sudo stuff will be stored in a config, not something you run on your local machine.  Next time link to the tutorial, describe your steps, give people something more to go on.  Or else you'll run the risk of having your question either downvoted or closed.  cheers

Comment: You can use windows - but it often a hell of a lot better to develop on the same operating system you will be deploying to. (or at least a unix system). You'll find better tutorials + Ruby might be cross-platform but like 99% of the gems are not tested on windows as its not exactly a priority in the ruby community.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Dokku to deploy from command line (With git).

More informations [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-dokku-application)

Comment: will go for this, cos its seems similar in deploying to heroku. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DigitalOcean has a "[One-Click Rails application](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean)" feature that would setup the whole environment for you. As the post explains, it works with Windows OS as well.

Also, Google has [tons of suggestions](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&q=digitalocean%20rails%20windows) on how to do it.